# In anger, I signed a letter to my wife saying talaaq thrice; is this divorce valid?

Tags: talaq, anger

A letter was sent out to my wife stating that I give you talaaq thrice. 3 points I want to make:

1. I was not in a stable frame of mind, I suffer from depression.
2. It was in a moment of anger.
3. I did not personally send the letter and I had changed my mind.

I signed the letter but did not post it out as I had no envelope, so I left the letter with someone who said they would get envelopes and post them out either later on or the next day.  Within 24 hours, I had changed my mind, but it was too late they had already been sent out.

My question is does this matter at all or does it not make a difference?

Comment: Did you sign the paper? Did you say that you divorce her? If you did, then it doesn't matter if you were angry or not, divorce will be valid. No man in his right mind will divorce his wife in a good mood. Of course people divorce when they are angry, so that is not an excuse.

Comment: Yes @SorrelVesper is right, but it should be kept in mind that anger and that condition should not be that intense that man does not realize what he is doing and what he is saying. Only than talaq is valid when man knows what he is saying and doing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because we are not a fatwa site.

Answer (score -1):

**Firstly:**
It is not essential or obligatory to have witnesses to the divorce. If a man utters the word of divorce, then divorce has taken place, even if it is in the absence of the wife or no one else was present. The same applies if he writes the word of divorce in a message or on a piece of paper with the intention of divorce; divorce has taken place in this case.

It was narrated that there was scholarly consensus that it is not essential to have witnesses to divorce.

> Al-Shawkaani (may Allah have mercy on him) said concerning the issue
>   of having witnesses to taking the wife back: Among the evidence that
>   it is not essential is the fact that there was scholarly consensus
>   that it is not essential to have witnesses to divorce, as was narrated
>   by al-Muwazi‘i in Tayseer al-Bayaan. And taking back the wife is of a
>   similar nature, so it (having witnesses) is not essential in that case
>   as it is not essential in the case of divorce. End quote from Nayl
>   al-Awtaar, 6/300

### So, if you knew what you were doing in that condition than talaaq is valid.

**Secondly:**
The fuqaha’ differed concerning the threefold divorce (talaaq). The correct view is that it counts as one divorce, whether it is uttered in a single phrase, such as saying “You are thrice divorced” or in repeated words such as saying, “You are divorced, you are divorced, you are divorced.” This is the view favoured by Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allaah have mercy on him) and was the view regarded as most correct by Shaykh al-Sa’di (may Allaah have mercy on him) and Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on him).

They quoted as evidence the hadeeth narrated by Muslim (1472) from Ibn ‘Abbaas (may Allaah be pleased with him) who said:

> At the time of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah
>   be upon him), Abu Bakr and the first two years of ‘Umar’s caliphate, a
>   threefold divorce was counted as one. Then ‘Umar ibn al-Khattaab said:
>   People have become hasty in a matter in which they should take their
>   time. I am thinking of holding them to it. So he made it binding upon
>   them.

### So, you may take your wife back without a new contract as long as she is still in her waiting period. Same applies even if you count this TALAAQ to be happened thrice.

Comment: I am confused. You have quoted a Hadith that is working AGAINST your conclusion. Previously it was One Talaq in one sitting but as mentioned in this hadith, Hazrat Umar ra changed it to three times in even one sitting means three divorces. If Hazrat Umar changed it and Sahaba didn't oppose him, it's called Ijma of Sahaba and thus the ruling has now changed. Please pardon me if I didn't understand your answer correctly.

Comment: That is exactly why there IS a second opinion of this type of talaq being 3 times. But the fact is that this decision was taken for the reason mentioned in same hadith that people had started saying things like i give you talaq thrice, i give you hundred talaqs and things like that with out thinking about what they are doing. Becuase they knew it will still be 1 talaq, To, solve this problem this decision was made. Now, if in an islamic state QAZI goes with opinion of this being 3 talaqs that will be counted as 3. And if qazi goes with opinion of 1 it will be counted as one.